# Personalised search ranking for hotels

Tags: recommender-system, word-embeddings, ranking

I've built hotel embeddings which gives very satisfactory results in returning similar hotels for each hotel.

Now the problem I'm trying to solve is to rank the hotels in order of relevancy to the user when they search for a location.

My current approach is to get the recent n bookings made by the user, average their embeddings and find the most similar hotels to this vector.

But this result is not satisfactory. Averaging hotel embeddings is not working as expected.

Any suggestions here?